# Preventing Prepared Statement Leaks using Checkstyles

Tags: java, jdbc, checkstyle, prepared-statement

Lets say I have the following code :

```
PreparedStatement ps = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
try {
  ps = conn.createStatement(myQueryString);
  rs = ps.executeQuery();
  // process the results...
} catch (java.sql.SQLException e) {
  log.error("an error!", e);
  throw new Exception("I'm sorry. Your query did not work.");
} finally {
  ps.close();   // if we forgot to do this we leak
  rs.close();   // if we forgot to do this we leak
}
```

and I wished to catch the scenario where I forget to close the `PreparedStatement` or the `ResultSet` using Checkstyles.  Is this possible, and if so, how would I go about it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PMD and Findbugs both have warnings for PreparedStatements (and ResultSets and Connections). I'd suggest using them for this type of warning, since CheckStyle has more to do with code style than finding data-flow bugs such as this.

Comment: But checkstyles builds the AST for your programs, so couldn't you do this with a custom check?

Comment: It's also worth noting that I'm running this in automation, not in my IDE.

Comment: Sure, if you want to spend your time writing a custom check rather than just re-using something already existing. I prefer to use Findbugs/PMD/Checkstyle to overlap each other, since each has some checks that the others don't - rather than choosing just one. Findbugs and PMD can run and produce reports just the same as Checkstyle.

Comment: Can you provide references to the rules in PMD and FindBugs?

Comment: I voted this up, but ideally I'd like to see if someone has a solution in Checkstyles

Comment: PMD http://pmd.sourceforge.net/rules/index.html search for "CloseResource". Findbugs: http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#ODR_OPEN_DATABASE_RESOURCE

Comment: I'm curious how rigorous their check is.  For example, if the resource is closed in a utility method, would PMD notice?  Thanks for the pointers and your excellent answer Matt.

Comment: It appears as though PMD would not notice, and trigger a warning.  Bummer

Comment: I would recommend using Findbugs. To detect this type of data-flow bug requires having type information. Checkstyle checks does not have access to this information, whereas Findbugs detectors do. Any attempt to do this check using Checkstyle would be a "hack".

Comment: Thanks Oliver.  Good to know.  BTW aren't you one of the creators of Checkstyles?

Answer (score 1):

We created a custom Checkstyle Check that prevents these Statement leaks. The code is down below.
The beauty of checkstyle is that you can customize your checks using an [API](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/apidocs/index.html?com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/api/package-summary.html) that exposes the Java AST. 
We have created tens of custom checks. Once you get the gist of it, creating new checks is easy.
We have also created a Subversion pre-commit hook that runs the check and prevents code with violations to get into the repository. The developer gets a clear message (see 'log' call below) indicating the problem and the line.

```java
import java.util.List;

import com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.DetailAST;
import com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.TokenTypes;

/**
 * Code blocks that invoke Connection.prepareStatement(...), Connection.prepareCall(...) or
 * Connection.createStatement(...) must have a finally block
 * in which there is a call to ContextObject.closeStatement(Statement).
 */
public class CheckCloseStatement extends CheckTcu {

    @Override
    public int[] getDefaultTokens() {
        return new int[] {TokenTypes.ASSIGN};
    }

    @Override
    public void visitToken(DetailAST aAST) {
        DetailAST literalTry;
        DetailAST literalFinally;
        DetailAST paramCloseStmt;
        List<DetailAST> idents;
        List<DetailAST> identsInFinally;
        String stmtVarName;

        idents = findAllAstsOfType(aAST, TokenTypes.IDENT);
        for (DetailAST ident : idents) {

            if ((ident.getText().equals("prepareStatement") || ident.getText().equals("createStatement") ||
                    ident.getText().equals("prepareCall")) && ident.getParent().getType() == TokenTypes.DOT) {
                // a Statement is created in this assignment statement

                boolean violationFound = true;

                // look for the surrounding try statement
                literalTry = ident;
                do {
                    literalTry = literalTry.getParent();
                } while (literalTry != null && literalTry.getType() != TokenTypes.LITERAL_TRY);

                if (literalTry != null) {
                    // good, the Statement creating assignment is within a try block
                    // now look for the corresponding finally block
                    literalFinally = literalTry.findFirstToken(TokenTypes.LITERAL_FINALLY);

                    if (literalFinally != null) {
                        // good, there is a finally block
                        identsInFinally = findAllAstsOfType(literalFinally, TokenTypes.IDENT);
                        for (DetailAST identInFinally : identsInFinally) {
                            if (identInFinally.getText().equals("closeStatement")) {
                                // good, there's a call to my closeStatement method
                                paramCloseStmt =
                                        findFirstAstOfType(identInFinally.getParent().getNextSibling(), TokenTypes.IDENT);
                                stmtVarName = findFirstAstOfType(aAST, TokenTypes.IDENT).getText();
                                if (stmtVarName.equals(paramCloseStmt.getText())) {
                                    // great, closeStatement closes the Statement variable originally assigned
                                    violationFound = false;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                // Exception: this rule does not apply to Xyz and its subclasses (which have
                // the same name Xyz followed by a suffix)
                if (violationFound) {
                    DetailAST classDef = aAST;
                    do {
                        classDef = classDef.getParent();
                    } while (classDef != null && classDef.getType() != TokenTypes.CLASS_DEF);
                    if (classDef != null) {
                        String className = classDef.findFirstToken(TokenTypes.IDENT).getText();
                        if (className.startsWith("Xyz")) {
                            violationFound = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (violationFound) {
                    log(ident.getLineNo(),
                            "Code blocks that call Connection.prepareStatement(...) or Connection.prepareCall(...) " +
                                    "need a finally block where you should call ContextObject.closeStatement(Statement).");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This custom check extends an abstract class that contains two utility methods shown below.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.Check;
import com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.DetailAST;

/**
 * Utility methods used in custom checks. 
 */
public abstract class CheckTcu extends Check {

    /**
     * Recursively traverse an expression tree and return all ASTs matching a specific token type.
     * 
     * @return list of DetailAST objects found; returns empty List if none is found.
     */
    protected List<DetailAST> findAllAstsOfType(DetailAST parent, int type) {
        List<DetailAST> children = new ArrayList<DetailAST>();

        DetailAST child = parent.getFirstChild();
        while (child != null) {
            if (child.getType() == type) {
                children.add(child);
            } else {
                children.addAll(findAllAstsOfType(child, type));
            }
            child = child.getNextSibling();
        }
        return children;
    }

    /**
     * Recursively traverse an expression tree and return the first AST matching a specific token type.
     * 
     * @return first DetailAST found or null if no AST of the given type is found
     */
    protected DetailAST findFirstAstOfType(DetailAST parent, int type) {
        DetailAST firstAst = null;

        DetailAST child = parent.getFirstChild();
        while (child != null) {
            if (child.getType() == type) {
                firstAst = child;
                break;
            }
            DetailAST grandChild = findFirstAstOfType(child, type);
            if (grandChild != null) {
                firstAst = grandChild;
                break;
            }
            child = child.getNextSibling();
        }
        return firstAst;
    }

}
```